# non-scope-sensitive alternative to get_object_vars?

Tags: php

Is there a non-scope-sensitive alternative to `get_object_vars()`?

I need to get all public properties from an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it inside a function.

```
$get_vars = create_function('$object', 'return get_object_vars($object);');
```

Now all you have to do is call `$get_vars($object)`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the [reflection API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php):

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public    $foo  = 1;
    protected $bar  = 2;
    private   $baz  = 3;
}

$foo = new Foo();

$reflect = new ReflectionClass($foo);
$props   = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);

var_dump($props);

?>
```